# Does SQLiteAssetHelper need open and close methods

Tags: android, database, sqlite

I am a rookie at SQLite databases and learning fast and my app is working fine and about to be finalise for deployment but I want to ensure I am using best practises and not have some hidden memory leak or other that will impact the app or users.

So I have markers that are recorded in a SQLite database and I use DBHelper and call the .open() and .close() methods before each read or write.

```
 public MySpotsDatabase open() throws SQLException {
    databaseHelper = new DbHelper(context);
    mySpotsDatabase = databaseHelper.getWritableDatabase();
    return this;
}

public  void close() {
    databaseHelper.close();
}
```

But how about for the SQLiteAssetHelper database?  I have hundreds of markers in a database that I load up and show on the map and again all is working fine but I am not sure if I need .open() and .close() methods for a readable only database.  Its being called on another thread so all good there but I can not find any information on the correct proceedure to open and close the database.

I followed the instructions from the GitHub:
https://github.com/jgilfelt/android-sqlite-asset-helper
but I can not find where to close the database.

**EDIT based on CL's comments.**

I am getting an error as follows:

**09-14 10:37:35.084 13951-13960/au.com.itmobilesupport.ausreefs W/SQLiteConnectionPool: A SQLiteConnection object for database '+data+user+0+au_com_itmobilesupport_ausreefs+databases+ReefData_db' was leaked!  Please fix your application to end transactions in progress properly and to close the database when it is no longer needed.**

Below is my SQL code for the SQLiteAssetHelper.  After more checking I am opening the readonly database but the issue is I need to close it.

```
public class ReefsDatabase  extends SQLiteAssetHelper {

    private static final String DATABASE_NAME = "ReefData.db";
    private static final int DATABASE_VERSION = 1;

    public ReefsDatabase(Context context) {
        super(context, DATABASE_NAME, null, DATABASE_VERSION);
        setForcedUpgrade();
    }

    public Cursor getStateData() {
        SQLiteDatabase db = getReadableDatabase();
        SQLiteQueryBuilder qb = new SQLiteQueryBuilder();
        String [] sqlSelect = {"0 _id", "state", "iconone" };
        String sqlTables = "Reefs";
        qb.setTables(sqlTables);
        qb.setDistinct(true);
        Cursor c = qb.query(db, sqlSelect, null, null, null, null, null);
        c.moveToFirst();
        return c;
    }
    public Cursor getRegionData(String whichState) {
        SQLiteDatabase db = getReadableDatabase();
        SQLiteQueryBuilder qb = new SQLiteQueryBuilder();
        String [] sqlSelect = {"0 _id", "region", "icontwo" };
        String [] theState = { whichState };
        String sqlTables = "Reefs";
        qb.setTables(sqlTables);
        qb.setDistinct(true);
        Cursor c = qb.query(db, sqlSelect, "state=?" , theState, null, null, null);
         c.moveToFirst();
        return c;
    }
    public Cursor getAreaData(String whichState, String whichRegion) {
        SQLiteDatabase db = getReadableDatabase();
        SQLiteQueryBuilder qb = new SQLiteQueryBuilder();
        String [] sqlSelect = {"0 _id", "state", "region", "area", "latitude", "longitude"};
        String sqlFilter = "state= '"+whichState+"' AND region= '"+whichRegion+"'";
        String [] sqlValues = {""};
        String sqlTables = "Reefs";
        qb.setTables(sqlTables);
        Cursor c = qb.query(db, sqlSelect, sqlFilter, null, null, null, null);
        c.moveToFirst();
        return c;
    }
    public Cursor getAllData() {
        SQLiteDatabase db = getReadableDatabase();
        SQLiteQueryBuilder qb = new SQLiteQueryBuilder();
        String [] sqlSelect = {"0 _id", "state", "region", "latitude", "longitude"};
        String sqlTables = "Reefs";
        qb.setTables(sqlTables);
        qb.setDistinct(false);
        Cursor c = qb.query(db, sqlSelect, null, null, null, null, null);
        c.moveToFirst();
        return c;
    }
}
```

SO how do I close the database?

Comment: It is common practice to have a single DB helper object for the lifetime of your app, and probably the same for the database object. That would remove the need for the open/close calls.

Comment: I have 2 different databases, one that has the 900+ locations (not all shown at once) and a empty one at the start that the user populates as they add markers to the map.   The one that is popultated by the user has the DBHelper but the SQLiteAsset database with 900+ locations does not have the DBHelp class.   So are you saying its best to not have a DBHelper for the SQLite database and just make the call Asynchronously?   Main reason for all this is I did not want a memory leak by leaving the read only SQLite database open.

Comment: The asset helper class is such a helper class. And you would still use the same helper object, just store it globally (in your application or main activity object).

Comment: Understood.  Will do.  I will try and post some code once I have it sorted.

Answer (score 0):

After CL's comments I have been able to work it out.   I had to still close the database so I changed the SQLiteAssetHelper class around so that open() and close() calls are from the Activity making the database call.

public class ReefsDatabase  extends SQLiteAssetHelper {

```
    private static final String DATABASE_NAME = "ReefData.db";
    private static final int DATABASE_VERSION = 1;
    private SQLiteDatabase myReefs;
    private DbHelper databaseHelper;

    private final Context context;

public ReefsDatabase(Context context) {
    super(context, DATABASE_NAME, null, DATABASE_VERSION);
    this.context = context;
    setForcedUpgrade();
}


    public Cursor getStateData() {
        SQLiteQueryBuilder qb = new SQLiteQueryBuilder();
        String [] sqlSelect = {"0 _id", "state", "iconone" };
        String sqlTables = "Reefs";
        qb.setTables(sqlTables);
        qb.setDistinct(true);
        Cursor c = qb.query(myReefs, sqlSelect, null, null, null, null, null);
        c.moveToFirst();
        return c;
    }


      private class DbHelper extends SQLiteAssetHelper {
        public DbHelper(Context context) {
            super(context, DATABASE_NAME, null, DATABASE_VERSION);
        }
    }

    public ReefsDatabase open() throws SQLException {
        databaseHelper = new DbHelper(context);
        myReefs = databaseHelper.getReadableDatabase();
        return this;
    }

    public  void close() {
        databaseHelper.close();
     }
```

Hope this helps someone.